# Type array length dynamically with Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to do type array length based on a number variable? example:

```
func(1); // returns [string]
func(2); // returns [string, string]
func(5); // returns [string, string, string, string, string]
```

Comment: Would this work? https://tsplay.dev/W4XPeW If so, I can post an answer.

Comment: @Oblosys: post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a recursive conditional type `StringTuple` to create string tuples of a specific length `N`:

```
type StringTuple<N extends number, T extends string[] = []> =
  N extends T['length'] ? T : StringTuple<N, [...T, string]>
```

`StringTuple` constructs the desired string tuple in an accumulating parameter `T`, to which an extra `string` is added until its length is equal to `N`.

```
type Test = StringTuple<3>
// type Test = [string, string, string]
```

Given `StringToTuple`, the signature of `func` is straightforward:

```
declare const func: <N extends number>(length: N) => StringTuple<N>

const t1 = func(1)
// const t1: [string]

const t2 = func(2)
// const t2: [string, string]

const t5 = func(5)
// const t5: [string, string, string, string, string]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wza53m)

Comment: hey, that looks promising! would you mind sharing a very simple example of what the implementation would look like? I'm having a trouble returning an array that would fit the returned type

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk You won't be able to this in a typed way, so you'll need to assert it with `as unknown as StringTuple<N>` (or just `as unknown` if the signature of `func` already specifies return type `StringTuple<N>`).